# "circular_buffer":"BlockDiagram::Filter<T>StampedValue" is not a valid template type argument for parameter "T"

Tags: c++, generic-type-argument

Following implementation leads to the error "circular_buffer":"BlockDiagram::FilterStampedValue" is not a valid template type argument for parameter "T".

Header-File:

```
namespace BlockDiagram {
  template<class T=double>
  class Filter {
   public:
    typedef struct {
        std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> tv;
        T  d;
    } StampedValue;
    typedef circular_buffer<Filter<T>::StampedValue> cbuf_type;...}
```

Cpp-File:

```
namespace BlockDiagram {

template<class T>
Filter<T>::Filter() {
    ...
}}
```

Unfortunately I have no clue what could be wrong in this implementation.

Comment: After you get that one fixed, you should have a look at: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).

Comment: Post a [MCVE] please. Are you missing `#include` statements?

Comment: You need `typedef typename` because C++ can't figure out a template member is always going to be a type on its own.

Comment: Also, please specify which C++ compiler you are using, it may make a huge difference.

Comment: (Or rather, you need `typedef circular_buffer<typename Filter<T>::StampedValue> cbuf_type;`